# wp_insert_post Only Once for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I have created a plugin that enables a Custom Post Type and I have inserted some default values for this Post Type with wp_insert_post.

```
wp_insert_post( array(
    'ID' => '3',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'exhibitor',
    'post_title' => 'Title',
    'post_content' => 'Description...'
) );
```

The problem is my values are reinserted everytime the page refreshes. I cannot edit or remove them.

How do I get Wordpress to only update a Custom Post Type when my plugin is activated? Everytime I refresh a page the posts are published again. So I cannot edit or delete the posts.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin use register_activation_hook, that's plugin function to be run when the plugin is activated.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'newplugin_install');
function newplugin_install() {
wp_insert_post( array(
    'ID' => '3',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'exhibitor',
    'post_title' => 'Title',
    'post_content' => 'Description...'
) );

}
```

hope this will work for you ;)